# Wordpress 404 with utf8 percent-encoded characters in URL

Tags: nginx, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

I don't know if this depends on Wordpress, Nginx, or what else... But I have this problem:

A wp site uses categories names as permalinks, like `site.com/catname/`. Those name are in arabic.

The url looks something like this:

[https://exampe.com/سكس-hd/](https://exampe.com/%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%B3-hd/)

which can be translated in 2 different ways:

https://example.com/%d8%b3%d9%83%d8%b3-hd/
https://example.com/%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%B3-hd/

the first one, with lowercases, works, but the second gives a 404. This creates many issues, also in Google indexing.

How can I make the 2 requests point to the same content?

---

this

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

In the index.php fixes the issue but it's a bad workaround

Comment: Could you move the fix to `wp-config.php` and perhaps make it more selective with a `preg_replace_callback` function?

Comment: So it's normal that this URL normalization isn't done by the core or at an higher level?

Comment: I tested some permalinks (without percent encoded characters) on my WP site and it is case insensitive. So I do not understand why percent encoded characters should be case sensitive.